# I want despeckling using Mixed-Attention mechanism based Residual UNET but I get different value errors

Tags: python, image-processing, google-colaboratory, noise-reduction

I'm working on grayscale images and want to despeckle Using Mixed-Attention Mechanism-based Residual UNET but I always get different value errors and I cannot get rid of it.
Here is the code

```
# Define the image size and batch size
img_size = (224, 224)
batch_size = 32

# Define the data generator for loading the images
data_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255, validation_split=0.2)

train_generator = data_generator.flow_from_directory(
    data_path,
    target_size=(224, 224, 1),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical',
    subset='training',
    color_mode='grayscale'
)

test_generator = data_generator.flow_from_directory(
    data_path,
    target_size=(224, 224, 1),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical',
    subset='validation',
    color_mode='grayscale'
)

# Get the number of classes
num_classes = len(train_generator.class_indices)

# Get the training and validation data
x_train, y_train = train_generator.next()
x_test, y_test = test_generator.next()

# Print the shape of the data
print('Training data shape:', x_train.shape, y_train.shape)
print('Test data shape:', x_test.shape, y_test.shape)
print('Number of classes:', num_classes)


# defining the model architecture

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import Input, Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, BatchNormalization, Activation, Add, Concatenate
from tensorflow.keras.layers import MaxPooling2D, UpSampling2D, Dropout, SpatialDropout2D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Multiply, GlobalAveragePooling2D, Reshape, Dense

def resblock(x_in, filters, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', dropout_rate=0.0):
    x = Conv2D(filters, kernel_size, padding='same')(x_in)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation(activation)(x)
    if dropout_rate > 0.0:
        x = SpatialDropout2D(dropout_rate)(x)
    x = Conv2D(filters, kernel_size, padding='same')(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation(activation)(x)
    if dropout_rate > 0.0:
        x = SpatialDropout2D(dropout_rate)(x)
    if x_in.shape[-1] != filters:
        x_in = Conv2D(filters, 1, padding='same')(x_in)
    x = Add()([x_in, x])
    return x


def attention_block(x_in, g, filters, activation='relu'):
    theta_x = Conv2D(filters, 1, strides=(1,1))(x_in)
    phi_g = Conv2D(filters, 1, strides=(1,1))(g)
    f = Activation(activation)(Add()([theta_x, phi_g]))
    f = Conv2D(1, 1, strides=(1,1))(f)
    f = Activation('sigmoid')(f)
    y = Multiply()([f, x_in])
    return y

def residual_unet(input_shape=(224, 224, 1), n_filters=32, dropout_rate=0.2):
    inputs = Input(input_shape)
    x = inputs

    skips = []
    for i in range(4):
        filters = n_filters * (2**i)
        x = resblock(x, filters, dropout_rate=dropout_rate)
        skips.append(x)
        x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(x)

    x = resblock(x, n_filters*16, dropout_rate=dropout_rate)

    for i in range(3, -1, -1):
        filters = n_filters * (2**i)
        x = UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(x)
        x = Concatenate()([x, skips[i]])
        x = resblock(x, filters, dropout_rate=dropout_rate)

        if i > 0:
            g = Conv2D(filters//2, 1, strides=(1,1))(skips[i-1])
            x = attention_block(x, g, filters//2)

    outputs = Conv2D(1, kernel_size=1, activation='linear')(x)
    model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)

    return model

# Define the model
model = residual_unet(input_shape=(224, 224, 1))

# Compile the model
optimizer = Adam(lr=1e-4)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='mse', metrics=['mae'])

# Train the model
model.fit(
    train_generator,
    epochs=10,
    validation_data=test_generator
)

# Evaluate the model on the test data
test_loss, test_mae = model.evaluate(test_generator)
print('Test loss:', test_loss)
print('Test mae:', test_mae)
```

What is the problem?
Where am I doing wrong?

I changed all the parameters regarding RGB in both the model and the train and testing generator.